# cordova(ios): iframe history go affecting parent window

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, apache-cordova

I have parent page with embedded *iframe*. If I call:

`domFrame.contentWindow.history.back()`

or

`domFrame.contentWindow.history.go(-1)`

parent window also receives that command and executes back, resulting in reload of application.
Is there any way to separate **history** objects of parent and child frame?

Cordova 6.5.0

Issue only with iOs, Android works just fine.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, still no luck.